# Genre featuring "chill scat singing" in a modern style

Tags: genre, similar-artists

So I'm getting into Lo-Fi Hip Hop [and there's this song I loved](https://youtu.be/sbExecJ9VKg). My favourite part is the intro. Is there something of the sorts of scat singing but with modern genres? It's really hard to find artists like Sophie Meiers, so I'd be so grateful if you could suggest me songs similar to her works.

Comment: If you're looking for purely for chill scat singing, check out Marvin Gaye's "[What's Going On](https://youtu.be/H-kA3UtBj4M)" at 1:43 and 3:03.

Answer (score 3):

Scat is generally a sub-genre of jazz, most closely associated with the 60's recordings of Ella Fitzgerald.  While there are modern singers who do scat, they typically do it in the older styles.  It you specifically want a modern genre version of scat, your best hope is probably remixes of old jazz records.

There does happen to be a sub-genre that specifically mixes older jazz styles with modern beats --[electro-swing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electro_swing).  While most such recordings don't specifically include scat, there are a few, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JoJkZvsIaIM).

You might also check out Wyclef Jean's [Apocalypse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVu7ZWyixzE) --that's a one-off in the style, however.